# Scrolling down with a fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some social buttons, that I want to fix statically in my website. Even when the user scrolls down the social buttons should be positioned vertically centered on the right like this:

[image]

This is my current code setup:

```js
// Animate the element's value from x to y:
$({ someValue: 0 }).animate({ someValue: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) }, {
    duration: 3000,
    easing: 'swing', // can be anything
    step: function () { // called on every step
        // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
        $('.count').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
    }
});

function commaSeparateNumber(val) {
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())) {
        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    }
    return val;
}
```

```css
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css");
body { margin-top:20px; }
.fa { font-size: 50px;text-align: right;position: absolute;top: 7px;right: 27px;outline: none; }
a { transition: all .3s ease;-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;-moz-transition: all .3s ease;-o-transition: all .3s ease; }
/* Visitor */
a.visitor i,.visitor h4.list-group-item-heading { color:#E48A07; }
a.visitor:hover { background-color:#E48A07; }
a.visitor:hover * { color:#FFF; }
/* Facebook */
a.facebook-like i,.facebook-like h4.list-group-item-heading { color:#3b5998; }
a.facebook-like:hover { background-color:#3b5998; }
a.facebook-like:hover * { color:#FFF; }
/* Twitter */
a.twitter i,.twitter h4.list-group-item-heading { color:#00acee; }
a.twitter:hover { background-color:#00acee; }
a.twitter:hover * { color:#FFF; }
/* Youtube */
a.youtube i,.youtube h4.list-group-item-heading { color:#c4302b; }
a.youtube:hover { background-color:#c4302b; }
a.youtube:hover * { color:#FFF; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="list-group">
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item visitor">
                      <h3 class="pull-right">
                          <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                      </h3>
                      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading count">
                          1000</h4>
                      <p class="list-group-item-text">
                          Website Views</p>
                  </a><a href="#" class="list-group-item facebook-like">
                      <h3 class="pull-right">
                          <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
                      </h3>
                      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading count">
                          1000</h4>
                      <p class="list-group-item-text">
                          Facebook Likes</p>
                  </a><a href="#" class="list-group-item twitter">
                      <h3 class="pull-right">
                          <i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i>
                      </h3>
                      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading count">
                          1000</h4>
                      <p class="list-group-item-text">
                          Twitter Followers</p>
                 </a><a href="#" class="list-group-item youtube">
                      <h3 class="pull-right">
                          <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>
                      </h3>
                      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading count">
                          1000</h4>
                      <p class="list-group-item-text">
                          Youtube Subscribers</p>
                  </a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

What actually happened when I tried to position this

```
position: fixed; right: 0; top: 100px;
```

above the `<div class="container">` was, that the icons got moved to the position but the rectangles with the views included stayed at the same place

When I tried to move the

```
position: fixed; right: 0; top: 100px;
```

below the `<div class="list-group">` it was fixed but looked totally squeezed

[image]

Comment: You don't need any JS for this, use CSS alone: `position: fixed; right: 0; top: 100px;`.

Comment: Try to this http://rohitazadmalik.blogspot.in/2014/03/section-have-fixed-position-when-it.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is just updated code as you want

```js
$({ someValue: 0 }).animate({ someValue: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) }, {
    duration: 3000,
    easing: 'swing', // can be anything
    step: function () { // called on every step
        // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
        $('.count').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
    }
});

function commaSeparateNumber(val) {
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())) {
        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    }
    return val;
}
```

```css
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css");
body { margin-top:20px; }
.fa { font-size: 50px;text-align: right;position: absolute;top: 7px;right: 27px;outline: none; }
a { transition: all .3s ease;-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;-moz-transition: all .3s ease;-o-transition: all .3s ease; }
/* Visitor */
a.visitor i,.visitor h4.list-group-item-heading { color:#E48A07; }
a.visitor:hover { background-color:#E48A07; }
a.visitor:hover * { color:#FFF; }
/* Facebook */
a.facebook-like i,.facebook-like h4.list-group-item-heading { color:#3b5998; }
a.facebook-like:hover { background-color:#3b5998; }
a.facebook-like:hover * { color:#FFF; }
/* Twitter */
a.twitter i,.twitter h4.list-group-item-heading { color:#00acee; }
a.twitter:hover { background-color:#00acee; }
a.twitter:hover * { color:#FFF; }
/* Youtube */
a.youtube i,.youtube h4.list-group-item-heading { color:#c4302b; }
a.youtube:hover { background-color:#c4302b; }
a.youtube:hover * { color:#FFF; }
```

```html
<div class="container" style="height:900px;">
</div>
<div class="container" style="position: fixed; right: 0; top: 100px;width:250px!important;">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="list-group">
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item visitor">
                      <h3 class="pull-right">
                          <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                      </h3>
                      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading count">
                          1000</h4>
                      <p class="list-group-item-text">
                          Website Views</p>
                  </a><a href="#" class="list-group-item facebook-like">
                      <h3 class="pull-right">
                          <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
                      </h3>
                      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading count">
                          1000</h4>
                      <p class="list-group-item-text">
                          Facebook Likes</p>
                  </a><a href="#" class="list-group-item twitter">
                      <h3 class="pull-right">
                          <i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i>
                      </h3>
                      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading count">
                          1000</h4>
                      <p class="list-group-item-text">
                          Twitter Followers</p>
                 </a><a href="#" class="list-group-item youtube">
                      <h3 class="pull-right">
                          <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>
                      </h3>
                      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading count">
                          1000</h4>
                      <p class="list-group-item-text">
                          Youtube Subscribers</p>
                  </a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

and here is the demo working code example

**[Check Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m6984whw/4/)**

---

> if you want that your icon not squeezed so for that you need to manage icon's height and width responsively so that it will look nice

**here is the updated fiddle with Logo**

**[Check Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m6984whw/7/)**

Comment: @FooBar give me url or updated fiddle or update in question

Comment: @FooBar it's due to i have given width of only 250px; that's why just remove it and see it will work i have included updated demo Please check

Comment: @FooBar and if you want that your icon not squeezed so for that you need to manage icon's height and width responsively so that it will look nice

Comment: I will just upvote and accept your post since it worked in the fiddle. I just suck at designing :D I will probably not implement it because I am not able to it properly, whatever...

Comment: @FooBar if you not try today then how you will know that how you can make it work.?? dude so just make a hard try and you will gonna succeed